# Multithreading has no effect when working with Bitmap object

Tags: c#, multithreading, bitmap

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Program();
    }
    private static int prepTotal;
    private static readonly object Lock = new object();
    public Program()
    {
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        Parallel.For((long) 0, 10,new ParallelOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1}, (j) =>
        {
            DoIt();
        });
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"1 thread sum time is  {prepTotal} ms. Total time is {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms.");
        sw.Restart();
        prepTotal = 0;
        Parallel.For((long)0, 10, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3 }, (j) =>
        {
            DoIt();
        });
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"3 thread sum time is  {prepTotal} ms. Total time is {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms.");
        sw.Restart();
        prepTotal = 0;
        Parallel.For((long)0, 10, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 }, (j) =>
        {
            DoIt();
        });

        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"1 thread sum time is  {prepTotal} ms. Total time is {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms.");
        sw.Restart();
        prepTotal = 0;
        Parallel.For((long)0, 10, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3 }, (j) =>
        {
            DoIt();
        });

        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"3 thread sum time is  {prepTotal} ms. Total time is {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms.");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void DoIt()
    {
        var sw2 = new Stopwatch();
        sw2.Start();

        using (var bmp = new Bitmap(3000, 3000))
        {
        }
        sw2.Stop();
        lock (Lock)
        {
            prepTotal += (int) sw2.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run my test code(derived from original really complex code) I got following results. As you can see code running in more threads is almost 3 times slower. Is Bitmap constructor makes some blocking or what?

```
1 thread sum time is  125 ms. Total time is 132 ms.
3 thread sum time is  360 ms. Total time is 132 ms.
1 thread sum time is  121 ms. Total time is 127 ms.
3 thread sum time is  364 ms. Total time is 128 ms.
```

Comment: Are you doing your tests in Release?

Comment: How many cores do you have? Do you have the debugger attached? Are you running in release mode? Many things affect the performance somewhat. In release mode, outside of VS I consistantly got about an 8% improvement in speed with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` 3 vs 1.

Comment: I don't see why something like `new Bitmap` would be CPU-bound. Most likely, it's either memory-bound, or GC-bound. Adding more threads doesn't help you with either. Also, `Parallel.For` has considerable overhead for work as simple as this (for me, a single `new Bitmap(3000, 3000)` takes about 40ms).

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is that parallelism brings overhead. Just look at your time examples, best case scenario: `1 thread sum time is  121 ms. Total time is 127 ms.` Just processing the `Parallel.For` operation costs you about 5% in terms of time.

Comment: I´m running this in release without debugger on Core i5 (4 cores). I know that this code is nonsense for real using, but as I wrote this is simplest derivation from real code which makes huge graphics operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I just used a profiler see if my guess is correct, and indeed, `new Bitmap(3000, 3000)` is almost entirely memory bound. So unless you have a server machine with multiple independent memory systems, adding more CPU doesn't help any. The bottleneck is memory.

The second most important part happens in the `Dispose`, which is again... almost entirely memory bound.

Multi-threading *only* helps with CPU-bound code. Since the CPU is much faster than any memory you may have in your system, the CPU is only really saturated when it can avoid working with memory (and other I/O devices). Your case is pretty much exactly the opposite - there's very little CPU work, and where there is CPU work, it's mostly synchronized (e.g. requesting and freeing virtual memory). Not a lot of opportunities for parallelization.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand it.